# Eloquent javascript chapter 11 Promises Asynchronicity

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, es6-promise

Im busy with **Eloquent Javascript chapter 11** and on the exercise of building your own  Promise.all function which acts exactly like the built in one.This is the defenition i made after seeing the Authors but unless i use setTimeout for executing resolve() for the promise to resolve, an empty array is what resolve recieves.

```
function Promise_all(promises) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
let pending = promises.length;
let output = [];

for(let  i = 0 ;i < promises.length;i++){
promises[i].then((v)=>{output[i] = v;pending--}).catch((error)=>{reject(error)})    
}
if(pending == 0){resolve(output)}
//I would have to do something like this 
//setTimeout(()=>{if(pending == 0){resolve(output)}},100)
  });
}
```

While a similar defenition by the Auothor works.

```
function Promise_all(promises) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let results = [];
    let pending = promises.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < promises.length; i++) {
      promises[i].then(result => {
        results[i] = result;
        pending--;
        if (pending == 0) resolve(results);
      }).catch(reject);
    }
    if (promises.length == 0) resolve(results);
  });
};
```

So since A promise is asynchronous how is the code above by the Author able to return a already filled out array if the callbacks passed to the promises might not have run yet. :)

Comment: you check pending outside the for loop - outside any asynchronous code and pending would always be promises.length at that point - the proper code checks pending inside the for loop inside a .then - so while you say the definition is *similar* it's actually *completely different*

Comment: ahhhh :) Thank you i see.So if i understand what you are saying beacuse I check pending outside the loop.Some of the promises may not have resolved or rejected so i could get an empty array.The right code though checks pending inside the then so when the last then runs it ,the exucution of all the promises has finished.Or something like that and i get it.Thank you :)

Comment: *some of the promises* ... no, the actual result is that **none** of the `result => {` code will have executed ...

Comment: I got it that block of code (result) doesent run or anything similar to it in my code, which runs in the authors code  .Which is the root of the problem if i understood